# Setup Blocked installing VS2015 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, windows-server-2012-r2

When trying to install Visual Studio Professional Editions with updates using the web install on Windows Server 2012 R2, I get a message that reads:

This version of Visual Studio Requires the April 0214 update to windows 8.1 and Windows Server R2 known as KB KB 2919355. Please install KB 2919355 before you install Visual Studio on these operating systems.

When trying to install the above mention update, I get the message:

"The update is not applicable to your computer"

Is it possible to install VS2015 on WS2012 R2?

Answer (score 2):

The VS 2015 professional 2015 with update 3 is supported on the Windows Server 2012 R2, and it requires Update 2919355, you can check it in here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx#3

For the update 2919355, you can install it through windows update or manually download the stand-alone update package from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355

Meanwhile, to apply this update, you must have the update 2919442:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919442 installed on Windows RT 8.1, Windows 8.1, or Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: @LAROmega, thanks for your correction and I have already updated it.